# left menu under content when resizing

Tags: html, css

would like to solve this problem somehow nicely.

```
<div class="leftmenu">
some menu
</div>
<div class="content">
some content
</div>
```

Well.. and the question is, what to write into css file to have "leftmenu" under "content" when resizing?

Assume that media query is in use, divs are next to each other before resizing and "leftmenu" above "content" after resizing.

Thanks a lot!
jiri

EDIT1:
the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nkkojmdf/2/
what I would like to have is yellow "leftmenu" under blue "content".

EDIT2:
"under" in previous is meant in 2D.

Comment: can you please add a fiddle...

Comment: sorry for incomplete question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally found the solution

```
display : flex
```

was what I wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/nkkojmdf/4/
Anyway, thanks for help!